# Perlbrew switch fails on docker build

Tags: perl, docker, perlbrew

I want to perlbrew on docker building phase. I successfully install a perl but can't `perlbrew switch` to it so `cpanm` installs the module into wrong place.

The Dockerfile is as follows.

```
FROM centos:centos7
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
RUN yum -y update
RUN yum -y groupinstall "Development Tools"
RUN yum -y install iproute cpan gcc perl-ExtUtils-Manifest
RUN curl -L https://install.perlbrew.pl | SHELL=/bin/bash bash
RUN echo "source /root/perl5/perlbrew/etc/bashrc" >> /root/.bashrc
RUN \source ~/perl5/perlbrew/etc/bashrc
RUN /root/perl5/perlbrew/bin/perlbrew install --notest --noman perl-5.30.0
RUN /root/perl5/perlbrew/bin/perlbrew install-cpanm
RUN /root/perl5/perlbrew/bin/perlbrew switch perl-5.30.0
RUN /root/perl5/perlbrew/bin/cpanm File::Find::Rule

CMD /sbin/init
```

It fails on `perlbrew switch` with errors.

```
Step 6/13 : RUN curl -L https://install.perlbrew.pl | SHELL=/bin/bash bash
 ---> Running in 2d003bbacf0e
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   170  100   170    0     0    189      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   189
100  1548  100  1548    0     0   1261      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--     0

## Download the latest perlbrew

## Installing perlbrew
Using Perl </usr/bin/perl>
perlbrew is installed: ~/perl5/perlbrew/bin/perlbrew

perlbrew root (~/perl5/perlbrew) is initialized.

Append the following piece of code to the end of your ~/.bash_profile and start a
new shell, perlbrew should be up and fully functional from there:

    source ~/perl5/perlbrew/etc/bashrc

Simply run `perlbrew` for usage details.

Happy brewing!

## Installing patchperl

## Done.
Removing intermediate container 2d003bbacf0e
 ---> cf3fe0430858
Step 7/13 : RUN echo "source /root/perl5/perlbrew/etc/bashrc" >> /root/.bashrc
 ---> Running in 835a04a14f9f
Removing intermediate container 835a04a14f9f
 ---> d06c29928706
Step 8/13 : RUN \source ~/perl5/perlbrew/etc/bashrc
 ---> Running in e655fe87bc0c
Removing intermediate container e655fe87bc0c
 ---> fbc2aa1dcbb7
Step 9/13 : RUN /root/perl5/perlbrew/bin/perlbrew install --notest --noman perl-5.30.0
 ---> Running in 1bb4851a6e5d
Fetching perl 5.30.0 as /root/perl5/perlbrew/dists/perl-5.30.0.tar.gz
Download http://www.cpan.org/src/5.0/perl-5.30.0.tar.gz to /root/perl5/perlbrew/dists/perl-5.30.0.tar.gz
Installing /root/perl5/perlbrew/build/perl-5.30.0/perl-5.30.0 into ~/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.0

This could take a while. You can run the following command on another shell to track the status:

  tail -f ~/perl5/perlbrew/build.perl-5.30.0.log

perl-5.30.0 is successfully installed.
Removing intermediate container 1bb4851a6e5d
 ---> 5c2f139f28c4
Step 10/13 : RUN /root/perl5/perlbrew/bin/perlbrew install-cpanm
 ---> Running in c8650ea79674

cpanm is installed to

    /root/perl5/perlbrew/bin/cpanm

Removing intermediate container c8650ea79674
 ---> c3e92218cf8f
Step 11/13 : RUN /root/perl5/perlbrew/bin/perlbrew switch perl-5.30.0
 ---> Running in 551369fc6a61
Use of uninitialized value $shell in pattern match (m//) at /root/perl5/perlbrew/bin/perlbrew line 2445.
Use of uninitialized value $shell in concatenation (.) or string at /root/perl5/perlbrew/bin/perlbrew line 2485.

A sub-shell is launched with perl-5.30.0 as the activated perl. Run 'exit' to finish it.

HOSTNAME=551369fc6a61
SHELL=
PATH=/root/perl5/perlbrew/bin:/root/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
_=/usr/bin/env
PWD=/
HOME=/root
SHLVL=2
PERLBREW_PERL=perl-5.30.0
PERLBREW_VERSION=0.86
MANPATH=/root/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.0/man:
PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT=
PERL5LIB=
PERLBREW_MANPATH=/root/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.0/man
PERLBREW_LIB=
PERLBREW_SKIP_INIT=1
PERLBREW_PATH=/root/perl5/perlbrew/bin:/root/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.0/bin
PERLBREW_ROOT=/root/perl5/perlbrew
Removing intermediate container 551369fc6a61
 ---> b76db56bd82f
Step 12/13 : RUN /root/perl5/perlbrew/bin/cpanm File::Find::Rule
 ---> Running in 5574895c6069
--> Working on File::Find::Rule
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/R/RC/RCLAMP/File-Find-Rule-0.34.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring File-Find-Rule-0.34 ... OK
==> Found dependencies: Test::More, Text::Glob, Number::Compare
--> Working on Test::More
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/E/EX/EXODIST/Test-Simple-1.302167.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring Test-Simple-1.302167 ... OK
Building and testing Test-Simple-1.302167 ... OK
Successfully installed Test-Simple-1.302167
--> Working on Text::Glob
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/R/RC/RCLAMP/Text-Glob-0.11.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring Text-Glob-0.11 ... OK
Building and testing Text-Glob-0.11 ... OK
Successfully installed Text-Glob-0.11
--> Working on Number::Compare
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/R/RC/RCLAMP/Number-Compare-0.03.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring Number-Compare-0.03 ... OK
Building and testing Number-Compare-0.03 ... OK
Successfully installed Number-Compare-0.03
Building and testing File-Find-Rule-0.34 ... OK
Successfully installed File-Find-Rule-0.34
4 distributions installed
Removing intermediate container 5574895c6069
 ---> b7cbd8213dcc
Step 13/13 : CMD /sbin/init
 ---> Running in 3180df4e4deb
Removing intermediate container 3180df4e4deb
 ---> b6ebc0ca82a5
Successfully built b6ebc0ca82a5
```

I also tried to switch/use perl-5.28.2 on centos7/ubuntu and results the same.
It fails only on building stage and I can `perlbrew switch` successfully by attaching to the container after building.

The direct cause of this seems to be the lack of `shell` environment variable in the sub shell forked in perlbrew swich/use.

```
Use of uninitialized value $shell in pattern match (m//) at /root/perl5/perlbrew/bin/perlbrew line 2445.
```

How can I solve the problem?

My environment is

```
App::Perlbrew 0.86
Docker version 19.03.1, build 74b1e89
```

Comment: Successfully built 3d1ea879e226 ?

Comment: why not using the official docker image for perl? it'd be a simple `docker pull perl:5.30`

Comment: Try setting the `SHELL` variable explicitly in `Dockerfile` like this: `RUN curl -L https://install.perlbrew.pl | SHELL=/bin/bash bash`

Comment: uh, the output doesn't match the script. The output says Step 9/11 is `Step 9/11 : RUN /root/perl5/perlbrew/bin/perlbrew install --notest --noman perl-5.30.0`  is followed by `RUN /root/perl5/perlbrew/bin/perlbrew use perl-5.30.0`, but you claim it's followed by `RUN /root/perl5/perlbrew/bin/perlbrew install-cpanm` and that the command that did run is nowhere in the script.

Comment: @HåkonHægland Thanks. I tried what your saying and there was not change. I updated the question.

Comment: @ikegami Thanks for pointing it. Now I'm sure the code and the log is corresponding.

Comment: @Stefano There is some reasons but I'll also consider your suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you trying to run `perlbrew switch` in a non-interactive shell? I don't understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @melpomene I'd like to `cpanm` some modules after switch.

Comment: @user3203239 If you look at the output from `cpanm` it says `Successfully installed File-Find-Rule-0.34` so it seems to be working, right?

Comment: Sorry for my duplicate question. My issue was solved by reading past Q&A and my script now is `RUN /root/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.28.2/bin/perl -S /root/perl5/perlbrew/bin/cpanm File::Find::Rule` without switch. Thank you.